# Center/Crop Images - Responsive Slideshow using Cycle2 plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design, jquery-cycle2

I'm working on a solution to crop and center images in a cycle2 slideshow.

I'm resizing and centering the image in the slideshow to the parent using [this plugin](https://github.com/levymetal/jquery-resize-image-to-parent).

Problem I'm having is that I'm centring the image after it transitions, but this causes each slide to 'jump' into place. I can't seem to find a way to center **all** images on slide init, and resize.

```
function cropSlideImage() {
    $('.cycle-slideshow img').resizeToParent({parent: '.slide'});
}

$( document ).ready(function() {
    cropSlideImage();

   $( '.cycle-slideshow' ).on( 'cycle-update-view', function( event, optionHash, slideOptionsHash, currentSlideEl ) {
      cropSlideImage();
  });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mwHk4/1/

Comment: I'd suggest using the images as CSS background-images on the .slide divs. Then you can size them nicely with background-size: cover and background-position: center.

Comment: This site needs to be accessible, all images need alt tags. Background images wont work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resizeToParent plugin will not work if the image parents are set to display:none. Because the resizeToParent plugin waits for images to be cached it will not run until after most of the slides are already set to display:none.

Initiate the slideshow programmatically using $('.slideshow').cycle() after running resizeToParent and everything seems to work as desired.

```
function cropSlideImage() {
    $('.slideshow img').resizeToParent();
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    cropSlideImage();
    $('.slideshow').cycle();
});
```

[Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/mwHk4/3/)

Comment: Very cool, this seems to work except on window resize.
Which is weird since resizeToParent includes a window resize event.
I tried to destroy the slideshow then reinit, but this doesn't work.

http://jsfiddle.net/mwHk4/4/

Comment: That makes sense actually. I think the resizeToParent code should be updated to ensure that the images' parents are always set to "display:block" when the code runs. If the parent is hidden then there's nothing to size the images to. Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/mwHk4/5/